# Keyboard Shortcuts in Google Chrome / Chromium Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I've created a basic [extension for Google Chrome](http://github.com/mmrobins/LastTab) to change the behavior of which tab is selected when you close a tab so that the selected tab is the last one you had selected instead of just the one before the tab you closed.

I want to add keyboard shortcuts, and I've found a way to do that using jquery and [jquery hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/), but the problem I'm finding is that the keyboard shortcuts only work once a page is loaded.  So for example, if you open a new tab without going anywhere, the shortcut keys don't work because the javascript only loads when a page is on the screen.  Same problem if you have the extensions page open in a tab.

Does anyone know of a better way to do keyboard shortcuts in Chrome extensions?  I've been looking through the [extensions documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html), but I haven't found anything that looks promising.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to hook into global hotkeys. The best you can do is add a window event keypress listener.

Source: [a Chromium developer post on the chromium-extensions group](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/c8f19e467f72ec37/c4739074713962e2?lnk=gst&q=shortcut#c4739074713962e2).

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the case, but it seems like for now there isn't a way to do keyboard shortcuts without interacting with the loaded web page.  I'll update with an answer if I find anything better.

Comment: Hopefully by the next release version, they will implement Global shortcuts. The current way I do it is with Window Events. Feel free to take a look at my reload all tabs shortcut extension:
http://github.com/mohamedmansour/chrome-extensions/tree/master/reload_all_tabs/

Comment: Updated link for Mohamed's project: https://github.com/mohamedmansour/reload-all-tabs-extension

Answer (score 7):

Just as an update it's actually being developed now:

http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/commands.html

Comment: this uses an experimental api. you can't publish extensions in the chrome web store using this api (publishing on your own website should be ok), and I think you will also have to enable something in the about://flags

Comment: Can't get it to work in Canary 23.0.1263.1. Also looks like it is not in the dev channel anymore :(

Comment: @RodrigoHahn It's not an experimental API that far in the future. Chrome Beta has keybinding support in non-experimental. I'm not 100% on the syntax, though. I was able to utilize the _execute_browser_action command (see here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.keybinding.html) on Beta, but I wasn't able to figure out the syntax for other, in-app keybindings. I suspect they are there, though!

Answer (score 5):

Keyboard shortcuts are implemented with chrome.commands in Chrome 25 and above: [developer.chrome.com/apps/commands.html](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Google Shortcut key like**           from [readrwrite](https://readrwrite.blogspot.com/) site
[GOOGLE CHROME SHORTCUTS](https://readrwrite.blogspot.com/2020/01/google-chrome-shortcuts.html)
Shortcut
Function
Ctrl + O
To open any data/file in internet search engines
Ctrl + N
To open new internet window not tab
Ctrl + Shift + N
To open new internet window with black background
Ctrl + T
To open new tab
Ctrl + F4
To close the open tab
Ctrl + W
To close the internet search engine
read more and explore all about [chrome shortcuts](https://readrwrite.blogspot.com/2020/01/google-chrome-shortcuts.html)