# Issue with adding a keyboard shortcut in an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build an extension for Google Chrome out here. When <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is pressed, the current tab should automatically redirect to a new URL.

The Chrome API does not give an easy method to assign a keyboard shortcut to an action, so I've used window.addKeyListener to watch for key presses. This is how my code looks like:

```
myKey=71;
window.addKeyListener('keyup', redirp, false);
function redirp(e)
{
    var mynewurl1=http://urlhere.com;
    if(e.keyCode==myKey)
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{"url":mynewurl1});         
}
```

(background.html)

But the problem is, nothing happens when I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the `http://urlhere.com` be in quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Background page is not visible, so it doesn't receive any keyboard events.

You would need to add event listener to content scripts injected to all pages, and then if your key is pressed send a request to a background page to open a new tab through API (or you can just change `window.location.href` from a content script).

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by making all the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: [Keyboard Shortcuts in Google Chrome / Chromium Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115083/keyboard-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-chromium-extensions)

> Unfortunately there's no way to hook
>   into global hotkeys. The best you can
>   do is add a window event keypress
>   listener.
>
> Source: a Chromium developer post on
>   the chromium-extensions group.