# How to write a Google Chrome extension that disables a default keyboard-shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need a Google Chrome extension that simply disables the built in <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> shortcut and pass it to the HTML accesskey as ordinary. (yes, that all - no configuration/graphics)

It's for an in-house web-application and I don't want to use existing extensions.

I've browsed the extension documentation but would be thankful for a jump start in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately there's no way to hook
>   into global hotkeys. The best you can
>   do is add a window event keypress
>   listener.
>
> **Source:** [a Chromium developer post on
>   the chromium-extensions group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/yPGeRn9y7Dc).

Related Question: [Keyboard Shortcuts in Google Chrome / Chromium Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115083/keyboard-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-chromium-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, (modified from http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript):

```
var isAlt = false;
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 18) isAlt=false;
}).keydown(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 18) isAlt=true;
  if(e.which == 69 && isAlt == true) {
    alert('Keyboard shortcuts + JQuery are even more cool!');
    return false;
  }
});
```