# extension shortcuts: temporally prevent all shortcuts from any extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It's possible to disable all shortcuts added by any extension. I want to disable them when the user is in a specific site.

If not, it's possible to know if a shortcut is already in use??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249790/how-to-write-a-google-chrome-extension-that-disables-a-default-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: @abielita you are right. However, that question is dated 3 years ago, I hoped things have changed since then. Seems not. I would like to know what Google thinks about this issue. I'm building a web app that uses lot of shortcuts and I cannot tell the user the reason of a failing shortcut, because I can't know which shortcuts are globals.